# Load More Button for Slick Grid

Tags: slickgrid

I need to create an add more button on the slick grid and didn't see an example for this. So my user would have the option of licking a "load more" which would then render more rows.

What is the best practice for this in Slick Grid? Is there an example for this that I'm missing?

Thanks! Great project btw.

Answer (score 0):

Do something similar to what the DataView does.

Write your own data provider that presents the "load more" as a row to the grid and use the grid onClick handler to trigger loading more data.